# Solution to an equation involving an integral

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I am stuck at how to how  solve the following equation involving an integral
$$ \int_0^t \sqrt{1+\cos^2x} \ dx=a,$$ where $a$ is some constant. Even if we take $a$ to be some numerical constant ,say,3,I have no idea how to solve it numerically. Any suggestions\hints\links are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The limits of integration and  the variable of integration cannot have the same symbol.

Comment: i made the required edit

Comment: It seems that it's the complete elliptic integral of second kind

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluation of complete elliptic integral of second kind](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378050/evaluation-of-complete-elliptic-integral-of-second-kind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's rewrite the problem as an ODE:
$$
J'(x) = \sqrt{1 + \cos^2 x}\\
J(0) = 0
$$
Now we need to solve $J(t) = a$.

Apply any solver with dense output (details on dense output can be bound in this [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-78862-1)). [This paper, p. 44](https://www.mathsim.eu/%7Egkanscha/notes/ode.pdf)  have dense output formulas for the classical Runge-Kutta 4-th order and Dormand-Prince 5(4)-th order method.

Integrate the equation until for some integration step $n$ the condition $J_n < a$ and $J_{n+1} \geq a$ holds. Having dense output means that method approximates solution for the whole $[x_n, x_n + h_n]$ segment as a polynomial in $\theta = \frac{x - x_n}{h_n}$:
$$
J(x_n + \theta h_n) \approx J_n + h_n \sum_{r=1}^s b_r(\theta) k_r.
$$
Here $k_r$ are the values computed by ODE solver for the $n$-th step and $b_r(\theta)$ are some known polynomials specific for the method.

Solving $J(x_n + \theta h_n) = a$ for $\theta$ requires solving a polynomial equation. If $\theta^*$ is the root of the equation then
$$
t = x_n + \theta^* h_n.
$$

Here's a sample implementation in Python

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return np.sqrt(1 + np.cos(x)**2)

def solve(a, h=1e-3):
    x_n = 0
    J_n = 0

    while True:
        # Classical RK4 method
        k1 = f(x_n)
        k2 = f(x_n + 0.5*h)
        k3 = f(x_n + 0.5*h)
        k4 = f(x_n + h)
        J_next = J_n + h * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4) / 6
        if J_next > a:
            break
        J_n = J_next
        x_n += h
    
    def dense(theta):
        b1 = theta - 3./2 * theta**2 + 2./3 * theta**3
        b2 = theta**2 - 2./3 * theta**3
        b3 = b2
        b4 = -1./2 * theta**2 + 2./3 * theta**3
        b1prime = 1 - 3 * theta + 2 * theta**2
        b2prime = 2 * theta - 2 * theta**2
        b3prime = b2prime
        b4prime = -theta + 2 * theta**2
        value = b1*k1 + b2*k2 + b3*k3 + b4*k4
        prime = b1prime*k1 + b2prime*k2 + b3prime*k3 + b4prime*k4
        return value, prime

    # Solving sum b_r(theta) k_r = (a - J_n) / h
    rhs = (a - J_n) / h
    theta = 0.5  # Initial approximation
    for _ in range(10):
        value, prime = dense(theta)
        dtheta = (rhs - value) / prime
        theta += dtheta
        if dtheta < 1e-12:
            return x_n + theta * h
    
    raise ValueError("Newton's method did not converge in 10 iterations")

exact = 2.54469990567338043284819761699
h = 0.5
while h > 1e-5:
    t = solve(a=3, h=h)
    err = exact - t
    print(f'For h = {h:.2e}, t = {t:.14f}, err = {err:+.3e}')
    h /= 2

# below is the program output
# For h = 5.00e-01, t = 2.54919537267950, err = -4.495e-03
# For h = 2.50e-01, t = 2.54551108196589, err = -8.112e-04
# For h = 1.25e-01, t = 2.54474240732528, err = -4.250e-05
# For h = 6.25e-02, t = 2.54469988714210, err = +1.853e-08
# For h = 3.12e-02, t = 2.54470055542287, err = -6.497e-07
# For h = 1.56e-02, t = 2.54469990566304, err = +1.034e-11
# For h = 7.81e-03, t = 2.54469990566925, err = +4.132e-12
# For h = 3.91e-03, t = 2.54469991247207, err = -6.799e-09
# For h = 1.95e-03, t = 2.54469990567352, err = -1.381e-13
# For h = 9.77e-04, t = 2.54469990567351, err = -1.319e-13
# For h = 4.88e-04, t = 2.54469990567351, err = -1.341e-13
# For h = 2.44e-04, t = 2.54469990705083, err = -1.377e-09
# For h = 1.22e-04, t = 2.54469990588198, err = -2.086e-10
# For h = 6.10e-05, t = 2.54469990568314, err = -9.759e-12
# For h = 3.05e-05, t = 2.54469990567353, err = -1.488e-13
# For h = 1.53e-05, t = 2.54469990567359, err = -2.074e-13
```

The other option that does not require dense output may be combination of interpolation with a quadrature formula. Let's use Gaussian 2-pt quadrature rule now:
$$
J_{n+1} = J_n + \frac{h}{2} \left[
f\left(x_n + \frac{h}{2} - \frac{h}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)
+
f\left(x_n + \frac{h}{2} + \frac{h}{2\sqrt{3}}\right)
\right]
$$
Again, perform steps until $J_n > a$ occurs. Do an extra step to compute $J_{n+1}$. Considering only 4 last pairs $(x_n, J_n)$ we get the following table
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c}
x_{n-2} & x_{n-1} & t & x_{n} & x_{n+1}\\
J_{n-2} & J_{n-1} & a & J_{n} & J_{n+1}\\
\end{array}
$$
Now by using inverse interpolation we can solve $J(t) = a$. Here is the Python code with sample implementation

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import lagrange

def f(x):
    return np.sqrt(1 + np.cos(x)**2)

def solve(a, h=1e-3):
    x_n = 0
    J_n = 0

    # Abcissae of Gaussian 2-pt quadrature on [0, 1]
    c1 = 0.5 * (1 - 3**(-0.5))
    c2 = 0.5 * (1 + 3**(-0.5))

    greater = 0
    xs = []
    Js = []
    while greater < 2:
        k1 = f(x_n + c1*h)
        k2 = f(x_n + c2*h)
        J_n += h * (k1 + k2) / 2
        x_n += h
        if J_n > a:
            greater += 1
        xs.append(x_n)
        Js.append(J_n)
        if len(xs) > 4:
            # Track only last four values
            xs = xs[-4:]
            Js = Js[-4:]
    return lagrange(Js, xs)(a)

exact = 2.54469990567338043284819761699
h = 0.5
err = None
while h > 1e-3:
    t = solve(a=3, h=h)
    err_prev = err
    err = exact - t
    print(f'For h = {h:.2e}, t = {t:.14f}, err = {err:+.3e}')
    h /= 2

# below is the program output
# For h = 5.00e-01, t = 2.54477389123962, err = -7.399e-05
# For h = 2.50e-01, t = 2.54471332799950, err = -1.342e-05
# For h = 1.25e-01, t = 2.54470126716086, err = -1.361e-06
# For h = 6.25e-02, t = 2.54469997330762, err = -6.763e-08
# For h = 3.12e-02, t = 2.54469991171027, err = -6.037e-09
# For h = 1.56e-02, t = 2.54469990844518, err = -2.772e-09
# For h = 7.81e-03, t = 2.54469990590587, err = -2.325e-10
# For h = 3.91e-03, t = 2.54469996551052, err = -5.984e-08
# For h = 1.95e-03, t = 2.54469916224480, err = +7.434e-07
```

Comment: ,this is absolutely wonderful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newton's method, combined with a quadrature formula. You want to compute a zero of $F(t)= \int_0^t\sqrt{1+\cos^2 x} dx -a$. So, take an initial approximation $t_0$ and form the sequence
$$
t_{n+1} = t_n-\dfrac{F(t_n)}{F'(t_n)}= t_n-\dfrac{\int_0^{t_n} \sqrt{1+\cos^2 x}dx -a}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t_n}}\approx t_n-\dfrac{v_n-a}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2 t_n}},
$$

where $v_n$ is a quadrature rule of your choice (Trapezoidal, Simpson, etc.)

$$
v_n = \sum_{i=0}^k \omega_{i,n} \sqrt{1+\cos^2 \xi_{i,n}}.
$$